# Is "quoteth" equivalent to "quoth"?

Tags: archaicisms

Could any given usage of "quoth" be replaced by "quoteth" (and vice versa)? Is quoteth simply its archaic form, or is there a difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Quoteth** is an [archaic third-person present-tense verb](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quoteth). Its equivalent modern form is 'quotes.'

**Quoth** is an [archaic first- or third-person past-tense verb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quoth). Its equivalent modern form is 'said.'

They are *different words* in *different tenses*. Both are archaic. **They are not interchangeable.**

Answer (score 2):

*Quoteth* is part of the early Modern conjugation of *to quote*:

> I quote
>
> Thou quotest
>
> He/She/It/One quoteth
>
> We quote
>
> Ye quote
>
> They quote

Today we don't use *thou*, and the *-th* become an *-s*:

> I quote
>
> You quote
>
> He/She/It/One quotes
>
> We quote
>
> You quote
>
> They quote

*Quoth* is a variant of the third person singular of *to queath*. While at the time that *queath* was still in use (it died out around the start of the Modern Period) you could have *he queþ*, but there was also a variant *he quoð* that went back to the Old English conjugation and likely survived because "he said" is such a common thing to say (ask a schoolchild who has done some Chaucer to remember a few words from it and "quod he"—the variant Chacuer used—will quite possibly come up).

Its use has been, for several centuries, restricted to deliberate archaicism, and even early Modern use is as a lingual fossil. Even in early Modern English, "he said" or "said he" would have been more usual than "he quoth" or "quoth he".

Amusingly, in uses other than third person singular it is simultaneously both very modern and archaic, as in it is used to deliberately be old-fashioned but it is incorrect (whether through ignorance or deliberate humour) in a manner not found before the middle of the 19th Century; probably because Poe's (archaic, but correct) use made it more well-known to modern English speakers than it had been.

The two words not only mean different things, but are less related than you might think, having completely different origins.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I indeed did not realize they were of different origins